# Proxypass nodejs app on subdomain with Apache 2.4.29

Tags: node.js, apache, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, proxypass

The app I'm using is [Lolisafe](https://github.com/WeebDev/lolisafe) and it opens a local port to 9999.

For my domain, I need the regular website to work (https://example.com) but also have a subdomain (https://sub.example.com) to link to the nodejs application which has a home.html page under **/srv/http/lolisafe/pages/**. Lolisafe also uses an API which calls under /api, so for example https://sub.example.com/api is how logging in functions.

All my domains files reside in /srv/http

httpd.conf:

```
Include conf/extra/site/domain.conf
Include conf/extra/site/lolisafe.conf
```

A Records are set for @, www, and lolisafe all with the same IP.

Currently my /etc/httpd/conf/extra/site/domain.conf file contains this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
DocumentRoot "/srv/http/"

ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com

ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/example.com-error_log"
CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/example.com-access_log" common
Redirect permanent / https://example.com/

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com
DocumentRoot "/srv/http/"

ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com

ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/example.com-error_log"
CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/example.com-access_log" common

SSLEngine on
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ca_bundle.crt
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/server.key

</VirtualHost>
```

And /etc/httpd/conf/extra/site/lolisafe.conf contains:

```
<VirtualHost *:*>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName lolisafe.example.com
    DocumentRoot     "/srv/http/lolisafe/pages/"
    ProxyPass        "/" "http://0.0.0.0:9999/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://0.0.0.0:9999/"
</VirtualHost>
```

Currently with this setup, visiting https://sub.example.com goes directly to https://example.com. What am I doing wrong?